# Performing an IDENTITY_INSERT using EF5 Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a POCO that I am trying to create via Code First Migrations and then seed data.  The problem is that I want to insert specific values into the identity column when seeding.

Here is my POCO

```
public class Result
{
    public long ResultId { get; set; }
    public long? TeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my AddOrUpdate call in the Seed method of the Configuration.cs

```
context.Results.AddOrUpdate
    (
         r => r.ResultId,
         new Result { ResultId = 101, TeamId = null },
         new Result { ResultId = 201, TeamId = null }
    );
```

As expected, it does not insert the values of 101 and 201, but instead 1 and 2.  Are there any DataAttributes I can apply to the model to help with this?

Comment: Do you want to disable identity inserts completely? Or just for your seed method?

Comment: Initially I was thinking for the seeding only...but if there was a way for Code First migrations to identify the ID column as a primary key but with Identity off, that would be acceptable as well

Comment: Are you using EntityTypeConfiguration<T>? If so you can use Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None). You could after the seeding turn this option off in your OnModelCreating and this.Database.Initialize(force:true); in the contructor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This how to turn off Identity via attribute/conventions

```
public class Result
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ResultId { get; set; }
    public long? TeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

This is how you turn off Identity via EntityTypeConfiguration

```
public class ResultMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Result>
{
    public ResultMapper()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ResultId);
        Property(x => x.ResultId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```

Or you can use the OnModelCreating overload

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Result>().Property(x => x.ResultId)
               .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Aron, I successfully inserted into the identity field using the attributes method you specified.

Comment: If the OP needs IDENTIY_INSERT, it's because they have an identity column. You can't just do away with that identity column to perform an IDENTITY_INSERT. Then you'd need yet another migration to turn Identity on again for that column. Much better to use raw SQL and not change the DB schema just for some inserts.

Answer (score 6):

### In case anyone is still confused . . .

*See below for additional info required to get IDENTITY_INSERT to work with Code-First Migration Seed() method*

I did use Aron's implementation of the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated` attribute to set the model ID's DB-generated property to 'None', but I still could not get past the identity insert error. I figured I would post my findings here in case anyone else is still having trouble.

To get it to work, I wrapped the seed method's logic in a SQL transaction and used `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable ON")` to allow the insert prior to running the `.AddOrUpdate()` method. Here is my Configuration.vb file (using a table for Google API types as our example data):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Migrations
Imports System.Linq

Namespace Migrations

    Friend NotInheritable Class Configuration 
        Inherits DbMigrationsConfiguration(Of DAL.MyDbContext)

        Public Sub New()
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = False
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = False
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub Seed(context As DAL.MyDbContext)
            '  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            Dim newContext As New MyDbContext(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString)
            Using ts = newContext.Database.BeginTransaction()

                Try

                    ' Turn on identity insert before updating
                    newContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT GoogleApiTypeGroups ON")
                    ' Make sure the expected GoogleApiTypeGroups exist with the correct names and IDs.
                    newContext.GoogleApiTypeGroups.AddOrUpdate(
                        Function(x) x.Id,
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 1, .name = "Google Cloud APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 2, .name = "YouTube APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 3, .name = "Google Maps APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 4, .name = "Advertising APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 5, .name = "Google Apps APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 6, .name = "Other popular APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 7, .name = "Mobile APIs"},
                        New GoogleApiTypeGroup() With {.Id = 8, .name = "Social APIs"})
                    ' Attempt to save the changes.
                    newContext.SaveChanges()
                    ' Turn off the identity insert setting when done.
                    newContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT GoogleApiTypeGroups OFF")

                    ' Turn on identity insert before updating
                    newContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT GoogleApiTypes ON")
                    ' Make sure the expected GoogleApiTypes exist with the correct names, IDs, and references to their corresponding GoogleApiTypeGroup.
                    newContext.GoogleApiTypes.AddOrUpdate(
                        Function(x) x.Id,
                        New GoogleApiType() With {.Id = 1, .name = "Google Maps JavaScript API", .GoogleApiTypeGroupId = 3})
                    ' Save the changes
                    newContext.SaveChanges()
                    ' Turn off the identity insert setting when done.
                    newContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT GoogleApiTypes ON")

                    ts.Commit()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ts.Rollback()
                    Throw
                End Try
            End Using

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 3):

After researching into this it looks like if the key was previously created and then you add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] in a migration it wont actually do what you intend, you can check this by going to the database explorer Table -> Keys -> PK -> Modify and see the Identity Specification is set to Yes instead of No.

If this is the case try migrating down to a point where that table did not exist and then remigrate back up.

Comment: You really made my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoMapper and using for/foreach mode, you must remap in for loop.

Example:

```
foreach (var item in Ids) {
    var page = Mapper.Map<Pages>(model);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    db.Pages.Add(page);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```