# Error in CodeFirst Seed with migrations : Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'CreatedAt'.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have activated migrations on my Azure Mobile Services project. I filled the new seed function Inside the Configuration.cs class of the migrations. If the tables are empty, the seed function is going without any problems. When my AddorUpdate tries to update the first object I get the error in the inner exception : "Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'CreatedAt'. Table: 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Category'."

Part of my code is as follows:

```
context.categories.AddOrUpdate(
            new Category { Id="1", Code="GEN", Text="General"},
            new Category { Id="2", Code="POL", Text="Politics"},
            new Category { Id="3", Code="FAS", Text="Fashion"},
            new Category { Id="4", Code="PEO", Text="People"},
            new Category { Id="5", Code="TEC", Text="Technology"},
            new Category { Id="6", Code="SPO", Text="Sport"},
            new Category { Id="7", Code="LIV", Text="Living"}
        );
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's my generic implementation of Nikatlas' solution.

Short version of the answer: You can't modify CreatedAt with a null value, so you can use this function instead:

```
    private void AddOrUpdatePreservingCreatedAt<T> (DbSet<T> set, T item) where T : EntityData
    {        
        var existing = set.Where(i => i.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (existing != null)
        {
            item.CreatedAt = existing.CreatedAt;             
        }
        set.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Id, item);
    }
```

Call it like this

```
AddOrUpdatePreservingCreatedAt(context.YourItems, itemToBeUpdatedOrAdded);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest band-aid fix thus far!

Comment: Your solution is good but I modified it to be really an extension method for DbSet and removed "Where" because it was unnecessary.
`public static  class DatabaseSetExtensions
    {
        public static void AddOrUpdatePreservingCreatedAt<T>(this DbSet<T> set, T item) where T : EntityData
        {
            var existing = set.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id);
            if (existing != null)
            {
                item.CreatedAt = existing.CreatedAt;
            }
            set.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Id, item);
        }
    }`

Comment: Does this mean that every upgrade/migration *all* entries will also have their `UpdateAt` updated?  I suppose this is sensible if the data **does** change during migration, but if it doesn't then it seems a shame to lose this data unnecessarily.  I guess you could add `item.UpdatedAt = existing.UpdatedAt` also, to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems i have found a solution to this problem.

The reason this error occurs is because of the `AddOrUpdate` Method. 
As stated in this post : http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

More importantly, if a match is found then the update will update all and null out any that weren’t in your AddOrUpdate.

What this means is that after the first seed, whenever your code runs it tries to update your entities correctly but it tries to pass the value null on `CreatedAt` field. If you look at EntityData class the CreateAt field has these attributes :

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] //Here they mark this as IDENTITY        
[Index(IsClustered = true)] // Cluster index. i really dont know why ?         
[TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]         
public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
```

So the error occurs beacause you try to modify the `CreatedAt` column.

My solution was to Create a List, lookup to set CreatedAt to correct value and then addOrUpdate:

```
 // Create List       
 List<Permission> permissions = new List<Permission>(new Permission[]{             
   new Permission { Id = "ID1" , Name = "Send SMS"},           
   new Permission { Id = "ID2", Name = "Send Email"}            });
   // Iterate through list to set CreatedAt to correct value 
   foreach (Permission p in permissions){
      // Get the record from the db if it exists              
      var t = context.PermissionSet.Where(s => s.Id == p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
      if (t != null){
         p.CreatedAt = t.CreatedAt; //SET CreatedAt to correct Value if the record already exists                
      }
      context.PermissionSet.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Id, p); // NOW I CAN UPDATE WITH NO PROBLEM
   }
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for this @Nikatlas ! I also took the liberty to post my genric method for your solution below, hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a integer column named `Id`, then Entity Framework will assume that is the primary key and that it is database generated - so it is created as an `IDENTITY` column in the database.

You cannot specify the Id for `IDENTITY` columns, so you stop doing that by removing the `Id = 1`, `Id = 2`, etc

I am a bit thrown by the fact that the column you have a problem with is named "CreatedAt". It sounds like it should be a `DateTime` and might also be database generated, but it surely shouldn't be `IDENTITY`?

Anyways, the usage you probably want is the one where you specify the natural key of the entity, so that EF can identify any records that already exist. So, if `CODE` is the natural key then you should be writing the Seed like this:

```
context.categories.AddOrUpdate(
   x => x.Code,//the natural key is Code    
   new Category { Code="GEN", Text="General"},
   new Category { Code="POL", Text="Politics"},
   new Category { Code="FAS", Text="Fashion"},
   new Category { Code="PEO", Text="People"},
   new Category { Code="TEC", Text="Technology"},
   new Category { Code="SPO", Text="Sport"},
   new Category { Code="LIV", Text="Living"}
```

);

Reference:
[Take care with the AddOrUpdate method](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/)

Comment: CreatedAt is an identity column in Azure Mobile Services. Check out EntityData class (although it shouldn't be in my opinion)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I am using EntityData. CreatedAt is an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

[This question, its answers and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258571/performing-an-identity-insert-using-ef5-code-first-migrations) might help you a bit, but not much.

You can do Inserts on identity column using the solutions provided by the question. But you cannot **update** values of Identity Column. The only way to do **updates** on identity column is to mark it as not being identity. Probably by adding manual migrations.

[This SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509564/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-set-primary-key-value) may also be helpful.

[Read here also on general MSSQL Server constraints on Updating Identity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947453/update-values-in-identity-column).

Answer (score 0):

SAME PROBLEM AND SOLUTION
We had the same problem and it was a trigger in another table that had impact on the table that we had the problem on.

DETAILS OF OUR DEVELOPMENT
We developed a Xamarin App connected to an Azure Web Service. When we used the method PushAsync from iMobileServices, it gave us the error: Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'CreatedAt'.

It was strange for us as some tables did not have the problem with the web service

REASON
It seems that the trigger update got in conflict with the pushasync from the mobile device.

We disabled the trigger, switched the responsibility to the front end and it worked fine. At least for us.

We hope this soltion helps someone.

[image]